# Stripe Retrieve PaymentIntents API. How to work with the output?

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the Stripe API to retrieve the details of a payment. The below code is what I have copied from their docs.

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('SECRET_KEY');
$stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve('pi_1234ABC', []);
```

I then simply print the output using `print_r($stripe);`.
When I run this is outputs the following object. Needless to say, this isn't what I was expecting and I can't find any other way of dealing with the output.

```
Stripe\StripeClient Object
(
    [coreServiceFactory:Stripe\StripeClient:private] => Stripe\Service\CoreServiceFactory Object
        (
            [client:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
            [services:Stripe\Service\AbstractServiceFactory:private] => Array
                (
                    [paymentIntents] => Stripe\Service\PaymentIntentService Object
                        (
                            [client:protected] => Stripe\StripeClient Object
 *RECURSION*
                        )

                )

        )

    [config:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Array
        (
            [api_key] => SECRET_KEY
            [client_id] => 
            [stripe_account] => 
            [stripe_version] => 
            [api_base] => https://api.stripe.com
            [connect_base] => https://connect.stripe.com
            [files_base] => https://files.stripe.com
        )

    [defaultOpts:Stripe\BaseStripeClient:private] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
        (
            [apiKey] => 
            [headers] => Array
                (
                    [Stripe-Account] => 
                    [Stripe-Version] => 
                )

            [apiBase] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the retrieve operation to a variable.  Something like this:

```php
$paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve('pi_1234ABC', []);
```

Then you can do things like this:

```php
echo $paymentIntent->status;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $paymentIntent;
```

That will echo the status of the Payment Intent, then a new line, then the entire Payment Intent.